# What can I do in this situation

Tags: arduino-uno

I only currently have 2 arduinos and I find that any project I build I feel bad because I have to rip it apart to get the arduino because I want to build something else. Is there a way to get arduinos for cheap? (I'm new to arduino)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly not "genuine" Arduinos, but eBay has many sellers in China and Hong Kong who sell boards that are just like Arduinos, if you're willing to wait several weeks for delivery.

I was able, just now, to find an Arduino UNO compatible board for US$3.59, plus less than $2 shipping to the US. Note that they do not come with tech support, and none of the profit goes to support the official Arduino developers.